# Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged or LostFocus?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datagrid

I bind a table of from a Database into a DataGrid using an Observable Collection:

```
class ViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private BDDInterneEntities _BDDInterneEntities;

    public ViewModel()
    {
        _BDDInterneEntities = new BDDInterneEntities();
        ResultatCollection = new ObservableCollection<Resultat>(_BDDInterneEntities.Resultat);

    }         
    public ObservableCollection<Resultat> ResultatCollection { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

This is my DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DonneesBrutes" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=.ResultatCollection, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="10,65,0,0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="PMRQ" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=.TOTMPMRQ, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" Header="PMRQ"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="LibellePMRQ" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=.LibelléTOTApres, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}" Header="Libellé PMRQ"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Ligne" Width="*" Header="Ligne"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="OTM" Width="*" Header="OTM"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="TOTM" Width="*" Header="TOTM"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="LibelleTOTM" Width="*" Header="Libellé OTM"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="GA" Width="*" Header="GA"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Discipline" Width="*" Header="Discipline"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="DisciplineSubstituee" Width="120" Header="Discipline Substituée"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="colonnesupp" Width="*" Header="colonne supp"></DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

One Way binding works well, I can see data from my table into my DataGrid.

I have searched about the possibility of being able to send data from my DataGrid to my Database and I found the TwoWay mode and the UpdateSourceTrigger property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger(v=vs.110).aspx

I think it's a great solution to perform this binding, but I'm not sure about what to do. Is UpdateSourceTrigger best property for me is LostFocus, PropertyChanged?
Is it enough to do this? My code only works on OneWay, the other way doesn't works.

EDIT1:
This is the interesting part of app.config File:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="BDDInterneEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ModelBddInterne.csdl|res://*/ModelBddInterne.ssdl|res://*/ModelBddInterne.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\BDDInterne.mdf;integrated security=true;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.entityClient" />
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use of the `Binding.UpdateSourceTrigger` property is fairly straight forward. It affects when property changes that are made in the UI are reflected in their data bound source objects in the code behind or view models. From the [`UpdateSourceTrigger` Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.updatesourcetrigger(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN:

> **LostFocus**: *Updates the binding source whenever the binding target element loses focus.*
>
> **PropertyChanged**: *Updates the binding source immediately whenever the binding target property changes.*

Which one you choose will depend on your requirements. If you want the `Binding`s and any validation that you may be using to update as the user types each character, then choose the `PropertyChanged` value. If you want the `Binding`s and any validation that you may be using to update as the user types tabs away from each control, or otherwise selects a different control, then choose the `LostFocus` value.

Now to clarify the use of the [`Binding.Mode` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.mode(v=vs.110).aspx), you should be aware of which direction the `OneWay` and `OneWayToSource` values work in. From the linked `Mode` page on MSDN:

> • **TwoWay** updates the target property or the property whenever either the target property or the source property changes.
>
> • **OneWay** updates the target property only when the source property changes.
>
> • **OneTime** updates the target property only when the application starts or when the DataContext undergoes a change.
>
> • **OneWayToSource** updates the source property when the target property changes.
>
> • **Default** causes the default Mode value of target property to be used.

To clarify further, the *target* that is referred to here is the UI control and the *source* is the data object that is set as the data bound data source.

Comment: Thank you for your anwser, If I have well understood what you clarified to me, I'll having to use `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` if it doesn't take too much cpu, and `Mode=TwoWay` which sound to be a mix of OneWay and OneWayToSource. I'll try it now.

Comment: With the TwoWay and PropertyChanged, I can see my Datas into the DataGrid but I don't see what I wrote From DataGrid in the table..
Am I missing something? I have this: `<DataGrid x:Name="DonneesBrutes" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=.ResultatCollection, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="10,65,0,0" AutoGenerateColumns="False" EnableRowVirtualization="True" RowDetailsVisibilityMode="VisibleWhenSelected">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="PMRQ" Binding="{Binding Path=.TOTMPMRQ, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>`

Comment: Does your `Resultat` class implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface?

Comment: eeh, ViewModel implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, but Resultat doesn't I think, I check.

Comment: I have now implemented like this: `public partial class Resultat:INotifyPropertyChanged` and I have two errors after having add `using System.CompomentModel`: `No connection string named BDDInterneEntities could be found in the application config file`, I'll edit my post with the app.config. And `WpfApplication3.Resultat doesn't implement interface member "System.CompomentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` solved by adding `public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged` added in the Resultat class

Comment: With this Edit, we can see I already have a connection string named BDDInterneEntities..

Comment: Can you help me please? I have build again the solution and I still have "one of the two ways" which don't work. The way Database => DataGrid works, but the way DataGrid => DataBase doesn't, I don't understant why

Comment: @Kraenys, you asked a question: *Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged or LostFocus?*. I answered that question. If you want to ask further questions, please ask one or more *new* questions. However, what you are asking is a bit much for this website. You are in effect asking for us to teach you how to use WPF and that is *not* in scope for this website.